# Polygon precision problem in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-3

I must do some really precise GIS work.

I edited a polygon-layer, deleted two polygons, created a new one and saved the edits. Suddenly a third polygon, which I did not change, is displaced / displayed in a different position, when zoomed to a scale of about 40:1.

Does anyone know, why this might happen and what I can do that this doesn’t happen anymore?

I’m using QGIS 3.30.2 and I think, I had the same problem with previous versions as well.

Here are two screenshots and further explanations:

I first selected, then deleted the green and red polygon. Afterwards I created a new polygon in the same layer (and more or less in the same position as the red and green previously deleted polygons) which shows a white boundary. Then I saved the edits. As you see in the second picture, the white line of another polygon which I didn’t change, changed its position. The polygon with the white line is part of the same layer as the green and red polygon. In the second picture, the black line appears, which on the first picture is under the white line.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

The polygon which changed its position was copied from the black-line layer to the edited layer some edit sessions ago. Therefore, it should still be identical to the black polygon.
Both layers have the same CRS (and the same as the project) and are stored in a separate gpkg.

To be sure, I don’t make something up, I deleted all the polygons of the white layer, copied the black polygon to the white layer and saved again. Then I just drew a new polygon over on the same position as the green/red polygon, saved and at this moment the white polygon was dislocated again.

Also, when I use the select by location tool and select the white layer equal to the black layer, the white polygon is not selected anymore.

This causes me a huge problem, since I need the data to be super precise and also since I don’t know which polygons were dislocated.

Edit:

I forgot to mention that the data of the black polygon is originally from a `ESRI FileGDB`, which I saved into a `.gpkg`. Up until now, I thought, this would not make any difference, since it is the same data, I save into another database.

Coming after the comments below, I post my project settings:
snapping settings:
[image: snapping settings]

layer rendering:
[image: layer rendering]

digitizing settings:
[image: digitizing settings]

Edit 2:
After further suggestions, I deactivated snapping and the "Simplify geometry" function.
Now I tried to reproduce the same thing again. I took the black geometry, applied `Fix geometries` and copyed the result to my editing layer. Then I tried what happens If I create a new feature which doesn’t overlap. And it seems like the white polygon only jumps, if I create an overlapping or very close new polygon.
The jump in the last example is only 0.272 millimeters (in the filed!) which is nearly nothing, but I want my data to be precise and not just nearly precise.
[image: Non overlapping, 2.8mm distance]
[image: Non overlapping 0.27mm distance]

I just found out that QGIS creates a additional vertex in the big polygon:
[image: added vertex]

Comment: My first thoughts in seeing this is you have a snapping or tolerance setting which might be causing the "jumps" in the data, or a rendering setting which makes a jump appear visually.  So you might indicate your project snapping settings, and your layer rendering and digitizing settings.  If your data is in a file geodatabase there will be a tolerance setting there.  There might be some useful info here: https://mapscaping.com/mastering-snapping-in-gis/

Comment: I don't understand why a snapping tolerance setting should make a polygon jump which I don't edit (I only edit the same layer).
There might be some issue because the data is originally taken from a ```GDB```. Do you know which format is more precise and how a previously in the ```GDB``` set tolerance might affect the data in the ```GPKG```?

Comment: I would start by deactivating the "Simplify geometry" option on the layer rendering...

Comment: Did you check that the geometry was valid in the original data source?

Comment: Thanks for those hints. I just added a 2nd edit. deactivating "Simplify geometry" did not help. I did not check, if the geometry was valid but applied ```Fix geometries``` to the dataset, before copying it to the editing layer. Therefore I guess it should be valid (and it is a simple geometry, it has only 5 vertexes).
I just found out, that QGIS automatically creates a new vertex when jumping (now it has 6!)

Comment: You also seem to have topological editing on, try without it if not already done...

Comment: Turning topological editing off solved the problem! I didn’t realize that I had turned it on. I still don’t understand, why it adds a vertex to the existing polygon tough. Thanks a lot @J.R